# ESRI Silverlight Template - 'View Designer' of MainPage.xaml Crashes Visual Studio

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api, visual-studio

At last, first adventure with the ESRI Silverlight API...

So, I have installed ArcGIS API for Silverlight v2.4 and all its dependencies.  Then, I downloaded the 'Showcase' Template.  Opened the project in Visual Studio Ultimate 2010, and the project built and compiled fine (with some warnings about ScaleBarUnit).  Hit F5, and application ran fine out of dev server.

Then, went to go look at xaml markup in MainPage.xaml by right clicking and choosing 'View Designer' option.  Xaml starts loading, then Visual Studio crashes.

I've spent the last hour or so googling the issue, and haven't found the fix.  I am hoping someone may know what  I need to do to view the xaml markup in Visual Studio designer?

Answer (score 1):

try this :
1- right click your solution 
2- clean solution
3- rebuild solution

you should install visual studio 2010 sp1

Comment: Good tip, usually works for me...